# Como posso converter valores RGB em pixels para uma imagem, em PHP?

Tags: php, rgb

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $altura; $j++) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $largura; $i++) {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);

    $imagem[$c] = $rgb['red'] + $rgb['green'] + $rgb['blue']; 
    $e = 9;
    $codigo  = round(($e * $imagem[$c])/765);
    echo $codigo;

    $c = $c + 1;
}
echo '<br>';
}
```

Por enquanto, o que o código faz é converter os valores RGB, somando-os para obter um número numa escala de 0 a 9. Quero que, em vez de printar números, printe pixels de tons de preto/cinza. Ou seja, quero converter a imagem para preto e branco.

Comment: Criar divs e carregar o background-color com as cores não resolveria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$img = imagecreatefrompng('imagens/monalisa.png');
$largura = imagesx($img);
$altura = imagesy($img);

$c = 0;
$imagem = array();

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);

for ($j = 0; $j < $altura; $j++) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $largura; $i++) {
       $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
       $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);

       $escala = $rgb['red'] + $rgb['green'] + $rgb['blue'];
       $cinza = round($escala/3); 

       $cor = imagecolorallocate($gd, $cinza, $cinza, $cinza);

       imagesetpixel($gd, $i,$j, $cor);
   }
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd);
?>
```

Consegui! Alguém comentou este link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php, pelo qual consegui descobrir o que queria. Aparentemente, o comentário sumiu...

Comment: Eu apaguei porque achei que não era o que você queria rs.

Comment: Pior que era... hahaha obrigado!